# UserForm ListBox Change not Updating TextBox Visibility

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm that has a ListBox named `EIDLList` and after that there's a TextBox `EIDLAmountLabel` and `EIDLAmountText`. I've written a snippet of code that is supposed to grey out both TextBoxes if the ListBox selection is set to "No" but for some reason it's not working. I've tried about 10 different variations using `Case`, `If`, `UCase`, etc and none work. I appreciate any input.

```
Private Sub EIDLList_Change()
If EIDLList.Value = "No" Then
EIDLAmountLabel.Enabled = False
EIDLAmountText.Enabled = False
Else
EIDLAmountLabel.Enabled = True
EIDLAmountText.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code , use `UCase` like this `If UCase(EIDLList.Value) = "NO" `

Comment: @MoKhalefa thank you but it still doesn't work. Both fields remain enabled when selecting No. Are there any References that need to be enabled for this to work?

Comment: Maybe you have a space before or after? try timming the value

Comment: @RicardoDiaz no spaces.

Comment: Am I nesting it in the wrong module? I placed it in the `UserForm` module.

Comment: Put a break point and step into with F8. Hover over EIDLList.Value

Comment: Yes, you are nesting it in the wrong module. Right click on the list box, Select view code and paste your code. I would also add `Me.`

Comment: @GMalc it's in the right place. By starting with `Private Sub EIDLList_Change()` it automatically assigns it to the `EIDLList` item within the `UserForm` 'module'.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I'm not able to do that with `Change` code.

Comment: If you are trying to make the text boxes invisible; use  `TextBox1.Visible = False`

Comment: @GMalc I'm not trying to make it invisible, I just want the fields disabled. (I did try it to see if it works but it doesn't.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the fields from `ListBox` to `ComboBox` and now the code works perfectly. Not sure how or why that matters.